# Will sequence file help in improve performance for reading in HDFS compared to Local File System?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, performance-testing, sequencefile

I want to compare performance for HDFS and Local File System for 1000 of small files (1-2 mb). Without using Sequence files, HDFS takes almost double the time for reading up 1000 files as compared to local file system. 
I heard of sequence files here - [Small Files Problem in HDFS](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)
I want to show better response time for HDFS for retrieving these records than Local FS. Will sequence files help or should I look for something else? (HBase maybe)

edit: I'm using Java program to read files like here [HDFS Read though Java](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for simple file retrieval grabbing a single sequence file will be much quicker then grabbing 1000 files.  When reading from HDFS you incur much more overhead including spinning up the JVM (assuming you're using `hadoop fs -get ...`), getting the location of each of the files from the NameNode, as well as network time (assuming you have more then one datanode).

A sequence file can be thought of as a form of container.  If you put all the 1000 files into a sequence file, you only need to grab 32 blocks (if your blocksize is set to 64MB) rather then 1000.  This will reduce location lookups and total network connections made.  You do run into another issue at this point with reading the sequence file.  It is a binary format.

HBase is better suited for low-latency and random reads, so it may be a better option for you.  Keep in mind that disk seeks still occur (unless you're working from memory), so reading a bunch of small files locally may be a better solution then using HDFS as a file store.

Comment: I don't get it. As you say "for each map task", but when does this map task takes place? As given here - hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/hadoop/… What is the role map reduce in simple retrieval of file? Also is it possible to get better results if I do concurrent reads (using threads) from single sequence file storing all the small files?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I have updated the answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll try out sequence file solution first and hope I get the desired results. I am using a Distributed file system for providing high availability and reliability, hence not using a local file system.

Comment: Are you going to be doing any batch processing or analytics on these files?  If not, Hadoop may not be the best for an HA file store.  Perhaps GlusterFS (http://www.gluster.org/) or MogileFS (http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/) would be better suited.